# Issues with optical flow implementation in Python using opencv

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, opticalflow

I have the following simple optical flow code. This reads the first two frames from a gif sequence and then computes the flow between them.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()

path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
video = cv2.VideoCapture(path)

_,im1 = video.read()
im1 = cv2.cvtColor(im1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
success = True

while(success):
    success,im2 = video.read()
    if success == True:
    im2 = cv2.cvtColor(im2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
success = False

hsv = np.zeros_like(im1)
hsv[...,1] = 255
flow = cv2.calcOpticalFlowFarneback(im1,im2, None, 0.5, 3, 15, 3, 5, 1.2, 0)

mag, ang = cv2.cartToPolar(flow[...,0], flow[...,1])
hsv[...,0] = ang*180/np.pi/2 # Error in this line
hsv[...,2] = cv2.normalize(mag,None,0,255,cv.NORM_MINMAX)
bgr = cv2.cvtColor(hsv,cv.COLOR_HSV2BGR)
cv2.imshow('frame2',bgr)
```

The above implementation is the standard openCV version for computing color coded optical flow. However I am getting an error in the line commented. This is because there is an assignment of a (m X n) vector to a (m,) vector as the error shows.

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (512,512) into shape (512)
```

hsv[...,0].shape gives 512 while ang.shape is 512 X 512

```
>> print(hsv[...,0].shape)
>> 512
>> print(ang.shape)
>> (512,512)
```

But the same code from the openCV website to compute color coded optical flow produces a output where a window pops up with some colored flow and disappears and then the following error comes:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (scn == 3 || scn == 4) in cvtColor,file /build/opencv-L2vuMj/opencv-3.2.0+dfsg/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp, line 9748
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "OF_Farneback.py", line 12, in <module>
next = cv.cvtColor(frame2,cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.error: /build/opencv-L2vuMj/opencv-3.2.0+dfsg/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:9748: error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function cvtColor
```

The code that I am refering to is the following:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv

cap = cv.VideoCapture("sampleSeq.gif")
ret, frame1 = cap.read()
prvs = cv.cvtColor(frame1,cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
hsv = np.zeros_like(frame1)
hsv[...,1] = 255

while(1):
    ret, frame2 = cap.read()
    next = cv.cvtColor(frame2,cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    flow = cv.calcOpticalFlowFarneback(prvs,next, None, 0.5, 3, 15, 3, 5, 1.2, 0)
    mag, ang = cv.cartToPolar(flow[...,0], flow[...,1])
    hsv[...,0] = ang*180/np.pi/2
    hsv[...,2] = cv.normalize(mag,None,0,255,cv.NORM_MINMAX)
    bgr = cv.cvtColor(hsv,cv.COLOR_HSV2BGR)
    cv.imshow('frame2',bgr)
    k = cv.waitKey(30) & 0xff
    if k == 27:
        break
    elif k == ord('s'):
        prvs = next
```

My questions are:

1. Why doesn't the original error appear in the second case, where the color coded flow is displayed inside the loop ?
2. How to fix the assignment error in the first code?
3. How to fix the error in the second code, which I guess arises mostly because it has reached EOF ?

Any pointers, suggestions will be helpful. Thanking you.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `hsv` is created from `im1` when the latter matrix is a greyscale one, ie it only has one channel. In  the OpenCV sample code, `hsv` is created from `frame1` which is a colour matrix, ie has 3 colour channels. The size of `hsv` thus varies between the two code snippets which I believe accounts for points 1 & 2.

With regards to point 3, the easiest way to fix this would be something like

```
while(1):
  ret, frame2 = cap.read()
  if(!ret): # ie there is no next frame
    break
  else:
    #code as before
```